# Filter Gmail spam based on content not address

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I have a Gmail account and a work email account which is not Gmail. My Gmail fetches my work account and places these emails under a special label. Good so far.

We have a request tracker at work, which sends emails with requests and a fair amount of spam to may work account—this is then fetched by Gmail.

I'm afraid of starting to report this fetched spam to Google as spam (because it comes from the request tracker email address) because then regular requests might be marked as spam as well. How is this done by Google? Is spam classification done by content/address/both? Is it safe to start marking spam? Can I do anything about it?

The best solution would be to prevent spam to be accepted by request tracker, but this is not possible right now.

Answer (score 2):

Gmail spam filters use complex algorithms that consider sender address, content but also by other parameters like volume of messages sent to Google.

You could help the algorithm to work better by marking the spam messages as spam and by removing from spam the messages that are not.

To learn more about how Gmail handles spam checkout [Spam and suspicious emails - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?hl=en&ref_topic=3395161)

Comment: Thanks @Rubén, that's an interesting point about marking spam and removing from spam. It might work after sometime, I guess.